# Handling upload file with file_get_contents()

Tags: php, csv

I have a PHP script that handles uploaded CSVs into a temp directory, I then have 5 lines of code to convert from CSV to JSON.

**My PHP Script:**

```
if (isset($_FILES['csvList']['type'])) {

  $validExtensions = array("csv");
  $temporary = explode(".", $_FILES["csvList"]["name"]);
  $file_extension = end($temporary);

  if (in_array($file_extension, $validExtensions)) {

    if ($_FILES["csvList"]["error"] > 0) {

      echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["csvList"]["error"] . "<br/><br/>";
    } else {

      if (file_exists("/var/www/tmp/" . $_FILES["csvList"]["name"])) {

        echo $_FILES["csvList"]["name"] . " <span id='invalid'><b>already exists.</b></span> ";

      } else {

        $sourcePath = $_FILES['csvList']['tmp_name']; // Storing source path of the file in a variable
        $targetPath = "/var/www/tmp/".$_FILES['csvList']['name']; // Target path where file is to be stored

        move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath) ; // Moving Uploaded file

        $csvFile = $sourcePath;
        $csv = file_get_contents($csvFile);
        $csvArray = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $csvFile));
        $csvToJson = json_encode($csvArray);
        print_r($csvToJson);
      }
    }
  }
}
$sourcePath = $_FILES['csvList']['tmp_name'];       // Storing source path of the file in a variable
$targetPath = "/var/www/tmp/".$_FILES['csvList']['name']; // Target path where file is to be stored
move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath) ;    // Moving Uploaded file
```

**The problem is on this line:** `print_r($csvToJson);`. **and this is the output:**

```
[["\/tmp\/phpYeuuBB"]]
```

This is the file path of my temporary file, what am I doing wrong?

**Here's what my CSV looks like -**

[CSV Demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ny9hyPtGrifh5OFWFbiQD-yFpkG3RbnFvoG_YQwwVPA/edit?usp=sharing)

**Update:** My JSON is not formatted correctly with " and \ next to names

```
{"data":["[[\"Debra Brown\"],[\"Jacqueline Garza\"],[\"Kenneth Foster\"],[\"Antonio Howell\"],[\"Fred Rogers\"],[\"Robert Stanley\"],[\"Jesse Price\"],[\"Henry Bishop\"],[\"Marilyn Phillips\"],[\"Charles White\"],[\"Dennis Lawrence\"],[\"Nicholas Thompson\"],[\"Chris Graham\"],[\"Louis Dean\"],[\"Katherine Green\"],[\"Janice Peters\"],[\"Bobby Wood\"],[\"Bruce King\"],[\"Diane Mills\"],[\"Jane Fields\"],[\"Amanda Gutierrez\"],[\"Russell Cunningham\"],[\"Judith Matthews\"],[\"Carol Franklin\"],[\"Jose Murray\"],[\"Kathryn Cole\"],[\"Katherine Gardner\"],[\"Lois Woods\"],[\"Andrew Bryant\"],[\"Victor Wright\"],[\"Adam Russell\"],[\"Tina Gilbert\"],[\"Shawn Boyd\"],[\"Wanda Porter\"],[\"Rose Morris\"],[\"John Mccoy\"],[\"Frances Gibson\"],[\"Willie Lopez\"],[\"Chris Reyes\"],[\"Craig Vasquez\"],[\"Diane Simmons\"],[\"Mary Little\"],[\"Patricia Fowler\"],[\"Jane Perkins\"],[\"Juan Brooks\"],[\"Bruce Howard\"],[\"Tammy Richardson\"],[\"Jane Gomez\"],[\"Tammy Matthews\"],[\"Matthew Fox\"],[null]]"]}
```

How it should be -

```
{"data":[["Debra Brown"]]}
```

**When I print `$csv`**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are inputting the path to your CSV to str_getcsv

```
$csvArray = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $csvFile));
```

Instead of your actual CSV contents

```
$csvArray = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $csv));
```

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning the file to the variable `$csv` but then you are doing this:

```
$csvArray = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $csvFile));
```

The variable `$csvFile` still contains the file path to your file which you previously set as `$sourcePath`. The actual file string returned from `file_get_contents()` is in `$csv`. If you change it to look like this:

```
$csvArray = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $csv));
```

You may find this resolves your issue.

Here are [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) for [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks, any chance you would know why my JSON has \ before it and quotes? Check my updated post.

Comment: @Kieron606 Firstly, do these slashes exist in `$csv` if you print that?

Secondly, what happens in `str_getcsv()`? Maybe that is part of the problem you're having.

Comment: `$csv` looks perfect

Comment: What happens in `str_getcsv() then? It might be worth asking a new question if this is totally unrelated...